# How to use this in Onclick html function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How do I use `this` in an `onclick` html function?

```js
function myFunction(C_this, tab_no, row_no, keynm) {
  $(this).parent().css('display', 'none');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="select-options my_new1 active" style="display: block;">
  <li
    rel="luxury car coloring book"
    onclick="myFunction(this,1,2,'package')"
    class="menew_22"
  >
    package
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do not forget to up-vote and accept as "the" answer below if this helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

You you need call `C_this` instead of `this`

Run snippet below to see it in action.

```js
function myFunction(C_this, tab_no, row_no, keynm) {
  $(C_this).parent().css('display', 'none');
  console.log('Div - Display: None')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="select-options my_new1 active" style="display: block;">
  <li rel="luxury car coloring book" onclick="myFunction(this,1,2,'package')" class="menew_22">package</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hidded, not removed

Comment: @JulienMaret no such word as "hidded"